# Checking a Button exists in Android

Tags: android, dynamic

Need some advice again.

I am 99% done with this module I'm working on, although I'm stuck at the last hurdle. I'm dynamically publishing a button on the screen at runtime. This button will take it to a new activity view when pressed. I got that working perfectly.

However, I have another button which randomly changes the view so it effectively needs to reset itself, if that makes sense. What's happening is each time the button is clicked (the dynamic one) it then adds another button to the stack. Effectively I have buttons each time I click running down the screen. Is my logic wrong or is there a way to check and prevent the button to show each time? i.e. Just once...Below is the code.

```
public void ButtonOnClick(View v) {


    Random rnd = new Random();
    int randomListIndex = rnd.nextInt(2);

    Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Page1.this, R.anim.fadein);
    int firstRun = 0;

    switch (randomListIndex) {
        case 0:

            //get the image your going to muck with
            image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cardImageView);
            //set the image with what it should be
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.storm);
            //apply the transition effect so it looks correct
            image.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);

            button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dynamicButton);
            button.setText("Need another question?");

                Button myButton = new Button(this);
                myButton.setText("Press Me");


                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.nextPageContainer);
                layout.addView(myButton);

                final Button myButton1 = myButton;
                myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        String activityName = "Storm";
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Page1.this, Page2.class);
                        intent.putExtra(ACTIVITYNAME,activityName);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });

        break;
     }
}
```

[image: attached is a screen shot to what I'm seeing]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: How about this? Add a new class field member (a class variable, not a method's local variable) that indicates whether the button was actually added in the layout.

```
private boolean buttonShown = false; /* Here changed */

public void ButtonOnClick(View v) {


    Random rnd = new Random();
    int randomListIndex = rnd.nextInt(2);

    Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Page1.this, R.anim.fadein);
    int firstRun = 0;

    switch (randomListIndex) {
        case 0:

            //get the image your going to muck with
            image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cardImageView);
            //set the image with what it should be
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.storm);
            //apply the transition effect so it looks correct
            image.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);

            button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dynamicButton);
            button.setText("Need another question?");

            if (buttonShown == false) {  /* Here changed */

                Button myButton = new Button(this);
                myButton.setText("Press Me");

                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.nextPageContainer);
                layout.addView(myButton);

                final Button myButton1 = myButton;
                myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        String activityName = "Storm";
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Page1.this, Page2.class);
                        intent.putExtra(ACTIVITYNAME,activityName);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });

                buttonShown = true;  /* Here changed */
            }  /* Here changed */

        break;
     }
}
```

**Edited again**: Instead of local variable myButton, I used class field member pressMeButton.

```
private Button pressMeButton;

public void ButtonOnClick(View v) {


    Random rnd = new Random();
    int randomListIndex = rnd.nextInt(2);

    Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Page1.this, R.anim.fadein);
    int firstRun = 0;

    switch (randomListIndex) {
        case 0:

            //get the image your going to muck with
            image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cardImageView);
            //set the image with what it should be
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.storm);
            //apply the transition effect so it looks correct
            image.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);

            button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dynamicButton);
            button.setText("Need another question?");

            if (pressMeButton == null) {
                pressMeButton = new Button(this);
                pressMeButton.setText("Press Me");

                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.nextPageContainer);
                layout.addView(pressMeButton);
            }

            /* If the pressMeButton is already in the layout, all you need to do is just changing the onClickListener. */
            pressMeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    String activityName = "Storm";
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Page1.this, Page2.class);
                    intent.putExtra(ACTIVITYNAME,activityName);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi Naetmul, I original had that in the code. The issue I have there is that it completely removes the button from showing on the screen. I still need the Button to show at least once per instance of being called i.e. the case statement is true then show the extra button...

Comment: My Apologies Naetmul, I see what you did there...let me change it and see if that works. I re-read your idea.

Comment: Got yours working but the issue is that when you pass the activityName to the next view it keeps the same variable i.e. Storm on both case statement....SO CLOSE....

Comment: I realized what you want to do. Replace the boolean variable to int variable which indicates the last button you clicked.

Comment: Maybe it's not necessary to do in this way. I'll edit the code again.

Comment: So you want to create a button for each case in switch, or just one button for all cases? If a button for each case in switch, you can make a button array. In that case, you will need *private Button[] pressMeButton = new Button[/The number of cases/];* and instead of if (pressMeButton == null) {, you will need to use *if (pressMeButton[/The index of this case/] == null) {*

Comment: Got it...that worked Naetmul! Thanks! Basically I needed to redo the conditional logic as you suggested additionally adding in the private Button statement outside of the logic to cast it correctly..

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine but the way it is it will always add a button to the screen. Whats the desired behavior your looking for? If its a conditional thing than you need to account for that in the onclick call.

EDIT:

So what you need to do then is to create some kind of flag or id for the button and set it as the button's view.tag like this:

```
Button b = new Button(context);
b.setTag(flagTag);
```

Then when you want to check if the button exists you check it like:

```
if((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.nextPageContainer))
   .findViewById(tagFlag)==null){

       Button b = new Button(context);
       b.setTag(flagTag);

    }else{
       //do nothing or something :p
    }
```

Comment: Hey James, Yeah I have a feeling there is something wrong with the logic. Basically where the image has two buttons that say "Press Me" I only want it to say it once per case statement. I have a nested OnClick which may be the issue but there has to be a way to check to see if the button has already exists on the stack...truly stuck .... I know how to do this in other languages just confused with the droid.

Comment: Dont create the tag inside the button click or you wont be able to reference it later.

Comment: lol i figured you might do that :p hey if it works how bout hooking me up with the answer :)

Comment: BAHHHH...can you do me a favour? with the code above could you give me a further example of what you mean...ti's not working.

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for your help. Naetmul had a different approach and worked out to be very good. Although I'm sure your way would have worked to. You and I had similar thoughts on how to approach it I just got it muddled up. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: no worries glad to help. basically if you declare your views to have tags that are exclusive to that particular view then you would be able to use the method I explained up above to find the view. It would also help if you had declared the linearlayout to be global at the top of the file instead of instantiating it from the layout each time as well.